# No Recording in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to record blazedemo.com with my Jmeter.

Steps that i have performed:

I Am using JMeter 5.1.1
Certificate Authority generated and imported into Chrome.
I am using jmeter in my office so it runs behind proxy and hence Checked that the port # in the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder matches that in the proxy server set up in chrome.
Have added a Recording Controller to my Thread Group.
Have added Cache and Cookie Managers to my Thread Group.
When I try to start the HTTP Test Script Recorder it does not record anything in the recording controller.
I have ensured that the selected Target Controller in the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder is a recording controller I've added to my Thread Group.
No Sampler/Requests are being added under the Recording Controller.
HTTP Request shows 200K.

Answer (score 0):

You don't understand the concept and the network traffic flow.

1. Configure Chrome browser (however I would rather recommend to use [Mozilla Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) as it has separate proxy configuraiton) to use **JMeter** as the proxy, to wit:

   - proxy host: `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`
   - proxy port: `8888`
2. [Configure JMeter to use your corporate proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)

This way the browser will use JMeter as the proxy so JMeter will be able to intercept and record requests and JMeter will use your corporate proxy in order to access the Internet.

An easier option could be using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/), in this case you will not have to worry about proxies and SSL certificates.